# splite something returned from a alias in my view an use in it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `cases` + view `allcases` + function `DateToShamsi` in my SQL Server database.

I have a column `CreateDate` in my view and another column `dbo.DateToShamsi(dbo.Health_Komak2.CDate)` 
and set alias "HK2CreatedDateShamsi".

The `DateToShamsi` is a function and generates `HijriDate` for example "1396/01/05".

I want to split HK2CreatedDateShamsi into 3 columns that are HK2Year, HK2Month, and HK2Day separated by "/".

What is the best way for this purpose? For best performance I have to use DateToShamsi just one-time, not 3 times (I can't use 3 functions to convert 3 time to Hijri and then get YY and MM and DD ! that's wrong) and I know I can't use Alias in view to split!

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Try this to find an answer. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

As far as splitting text, Simple `Substring()` function can be used to split the text like this:

```
select substring('1396/01/05',1,4) as [YEAR], 
substring('1396/01/05',6,2) as [Month], 
substring('1396/01/05',9,2) as [day]
```

in your case:

```
select substring(dbo.DateToShamsi(dbo.Health_Komak2.CDate),1,4) as [YEAR], 
substring(dbo.DateToShamsi(dbo.Health_Komak2.CDate),6,2) as [Month], 
substring(dbo.DateToShamsi(dbo.Health_Komak2.CDate),9,2) as [day]
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp

You can change your function to table valued function if you want to return the value into 3 different columns.

Please visit to learn how to create and use table value function: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: ,No, you use 3 times from DateToShamsi Function and it is redundancy and reduces my performance, I want to use the result of DateToShamsi and then split into 3 separate part!

Comment: well then maybe you should change your function as table value function and return your values into 3 different columns as year and date and day separately. As far as splitting of string goes. that is usually how you its done in sql

Comment: and can I use it in view and use 3 separate ? could you change please your answer to this solution?

Comment: Thanks, I change my code to table-valued function, but how I can get 3 of exported date in function in my view? 
select ...., (select yyyy,mm,dd from dbo.[DateToShamsiSepratePart](GETDATE())) , ... from .... ... it take this error : Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.